# Are input fields that don’t have name=“” sent via the browser

Tags: javascript, ssl, web, credit-card, stripe-payments

Are input fields that don’t have `name` attributes susceptible to MITM attacks (w/o SSL) or any other attack?

For example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="credit_card_number"><input id="credit_card_number" type="text" value="4111111111111111"></label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I'm doing is using javascript to get the values, then posting to stripe.js, receiving a token and then clearing all the values of the CC fields (even though in my tests the values are never sent) before submitting the form to the server (token field is the only thing received).

I understand that SSL would be a "good idea" but is it necessary to prevent attacks (e.g. MITM)? And "why?", if the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) says that a form field should only be considered valid if its paired with a name attribute so a browser should not submit a form field with no name (it can't anyway as there is no way to parse it into a query string).

This is not really related to an MITM attack; you would always want to serve your page over HTTPS to reduce the possibility of someone intercepting the request and modifying the payment page to harvest details and send them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If the form is served without SSL, then a MITM attack could inject JavaScript into it. That JavaScript could then read the form controls (even if they do not have name attributes) and send them to the attacker.

If you have a form into which sensitive information will be entered then you **must** secure the page.